# wishing a happy week

Tags: expressions

As a non-native English speaker, I have a question:

Can I write (and say) "Happy week everyone" to wish a good/happy week? Is there any more common English expression in everyday conversations?

Comment: Say it however you want to, but if you write it, it should be: "Happy week, everyone!" (The comma after "week" is necessary.) There are many ways of saying this, as the answers below indicate. Personal preference prevails.

Comment: A question like this one would fit much better on the [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/) site. Have a great week!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is nothing wrong saying "Happy week everyone", *happy* being an adjective and *the week* being a noun. But it will sound weird and out of the ordinary! something that the people are not used to hearing.

Being Native English speaker I would recommend saying "Have a good week(end) (ahead)" or just say "have a good one."

So, if you don't want to sound weird, don't use "happy week".

Comment: These salutations tend to become 'fossilised expressions', with illogical degrees of changes that might seem logically permissible actually employed. Thus 'Merry Christmas and a Happy New Year' is never swapped to 'Happy Christmas and a Merry New Year'; 'Merry Birthday' and 'Have a merry week!' are likewise no-noes (except for comic effect); and 'Have a happy week!' is distinctly non-standard.

Comment: exactly what I meant. non-standard.
:)

Answer (score 6):

As a native English speaker, I have seen "have a good week" used commonly in both spoken and informal written communication.  I have not seen the expression "...happy week" used by native English speakers.

Answer (score 1):

I am not a native English speaker myself but I have heard my native English speaking friends say, "Have a good week (ahead)."

Answer (score 0):

I know no English speakers who says *Happy weekend* the way one might say *Happy birthday* or *Happy anniversary*.

We just say

> Have a {good/great/fun/nice/pleasant/relaxing} {day/week/weekend/vacation/life}.

instead.

Answer (score 0):

It is very simple, just add a "big" word before anything you have to say and make it look important even though everyone knows it's not. For example, "Have a fantastic week"